# Using Bluebird to turn cordova plugin into promise

Tags: cordova, promise, bluebird

I am trying to find an elegant solution to turning a cordova plugin call into a bluebird promise and was wondering if there is a better way than doing something like this :

```
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                cordova.plugins.clipboard.paste(function (text) {
                    if (text !== null) {
                        view.show();
                        resolve(text);
                    }
                    else {
                        reject();
                    }
                });
            });
```

The cordova plugin function "paste" takes a callback function and in that callback I am resolving or rejecting the promise. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Do all functions use this sort of "`null` if error else resolve" convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a generic promisifer for cordova convention:

```js
function CordovaPromisifer(fn) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        var self = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            args.push(function(result) {
                if (result !== null) {
                    resolve(result);
                } else {
                    // For the stack trace.
                    reject(new Error("cordova error"));
                }
            });
            fn.apply(self, args);
        });
    }
}
```

Use it to promisify stuff:

```js
Promise.promisifyAll(cordova.plugins.clipboard, {
    promisifier: CordovaPromisifer
});
```

Call promisified functions:

```js
cordova.plugins.clipboard.pasteAsync().then(function(text) {
    view.show();
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Esailija. One comment for anyone else who is looking to use this as well. Make sure to have the latest version of bluebird. I had an older version(2.0.7) and the promisifier was getting ignored.

Comment: How about the cordova notation: `fn(success, failure)`. How could this promisfied?